# How can I use webpack-dev-server for React embeded in AngularJs directives?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on a project with AngularJS which is progressively being migrated to React, so for now we are using React on AngularJS directives.
The problem is that for every small change I need to run a *npm run build* ("build": "webpack --mode ")
Is there any way to use webpack-dev-server or anything else to see the changes "live" as I change the files? I can't find a way to make it work.

I'm using:
"webpack": "^4.43.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
"react": "^16.13.1"

Thanks in advance